jQuery+jQuery ui на Laravel 11 Vite
При подключении jQuery-ui возникает ошибка, до подключения UI, jquery работает хорошо,
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
    (анонимная функция) (jquery-ui_dist_jquery-ui.js:7)
    Код модуля (jquery-ui_dist_jquery-ui.js:9)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
    Код модуля (create:247)

bootstrap.js:
import * as Popper from '@popperjs/core'
window.Popper = Popper
//
import 'bootstrap'

import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

import jQuery from 'jquery';

import select2 from "select2"
select2();
window.$ = jQuery;
import 'jquery-ui/dist/jquery-ui';



import './dashboard.js';

vite.config:
defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/css/dashboard.css'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '$':'jQuery',
        }
    },
    server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost',
        },
    },

});

Вызов в коде:
@push('js_after')
        <script type="module">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#multiple-select-tags').select2({
                    theme: "classic",
                });

                $(function () {
                    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                        showButtonPanel: true
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
    @endpush

Прочел уже несколько десятков гайдов - ничего не помогает, прошу помощи.
